# Are physics questions unwelcome?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are physics questions not welcome on Math.SE? This question emerges because unlike my other questions, most of my questions related to physics are left unattended or with poor answers.

In my non-exhaustive list I am including even the two most recent questions in order to promote them. I realize it's early to say they haven't gotten enough attention.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628522/liouvilles-theorem-on-integrating-a-conservative-hamiltonian-system-with-n-invo

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627312/integrating-a-conservative-hamiltonian-system-with-n-involutive-first-integral

[A Proof of Bruns' Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502522/a-proof-of-bruns-theorem)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501066/bertrands-theorem-the-principle-of-least-curvature

[The equvalence of the virtual work and the Hamiltonian equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501050/the-equvalence-of-the-virtual-work-and-the-hamiltonian-equations)

Should I have those questions migrated to Physics.SE?

**EDIT:** Notice also that the type of questions that I asked, were also already questions about mathematical theorems, very much unlike questions arising from everyday life, such as [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088/why-this-particular-question-about-a-physical-phenomenon-got-closed), which may be more appropriate on Physics.SE.

Comment: It could be that one reason you aren't getting answers is that you are tagging them in a way that few people will see them. In particular you are using the "classical-mechanics" tags, although they questions seems to be just analysis, and you are using "reference-request" and "online-resources", which discourages people from just writing a proof. If you just want to know how to prove something, you can ask for that directly, rather than asking for a reference for another place where it is proved. And, I think, more people will see the questions if you tag them with the relevant areas of math.

Comment: -1 for self-promotion

Comment: If you do not get close-votes on your questions why do you ask a question about them being "unwelcome" or "allowed"?

Comment: This question has an answer like the answers in another recent question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12344

Comment: If it's about math, then why would it be unwelcome?

Answer (score 20):

Some physics questions are welcome on MSE, see for example the [physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) or [quantum-mechanics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) tags.  The key is that all posts must still be about *mathematics*, so the question will have to be about mathematics arising in a physics context. So, one might ask for help some help solving or understanding some physical equations, whereas something relying fundamentally on physical fact such as "what is the difference between alpha and beta particles" belongs at Physics SE. (In fact, I believe that the former type of question is somewhat discouraged at Physics SE.)

Anyhow, one thing I noticed about your questions that might be helpful to correct is that many things are left mathematically undefined, especially in your theorem questions. I know you're looking for references and aren't expecting for people to derive them for you, but including mathematical language makes it more accessible to math students and mathematicians, and thus more likely that we can tell you where to look.  As a general rule your question is more likely to be overlooked if the reader is required to look things up; my suggestion is to try to make the questions more self-contained.

Comment: Yep, at [physics.SE] we do tend to discourage questions that are mathematical in nature, even if the question arises in a physical context. We usually migrate such questions here when we see them. (There are, however, some questions that could be considered mathematical in nature but nevertheless are on topic on Physics; usually relating to more advanced topics in theoretical physics.)